# Maven skip recompilation of submodule

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, multi-module

This is my current project setup:

Parent

- Submodule A
- Submodule B <- Depends on A
- Submodule C

I have a multi module setup where the compilation of one specific submodule (A) takes quite a while. Since A rarely changes I'd like to skip it while recompiling the project. However I've run into issues because B depends on A. So executing

```
mvn clean install -pl !A
```

or using a profile like

```
<modules>
  <module>Submodule B</module>
  <module>Submodule C</module>
<modules>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>include-A</id>
    <modules>
      <module>Submodule A</module>
    </modules>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

fails because B cannot locate A even if it is present in my .m2 folder from  a previous Maven execution since it looks for that artifact on our Nexus repo.

It seems to work if I move Submodule A to a separate project but then I'd have to manage two projects with identical configurations so I'd prefer to keep my project structure.

Comment: If you are sure your submodule A is properly built, you can start your build with the option -rf :submoduleB, which will have Maven only build your project starting at your Submodule B and not at the SubModule A. However, whenever you will release your project, always make a full build of it

Comment: Thanks for the idea however it fails with the same error because it still cannot resolve the dependency A

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution but you could consolidate submodules B and C under another module like this:

Parent

- Submodule A
- Sub Parent

  - Submodule B
  - Submodule C

Now you should be able to `cd` into the Sub Parent folder and build only submodules B and C.